# SSL certificate(Virginia region ) not working

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

Hi Everyone I am using aws Ec2 instance for magento site and trying to install ssl certificate .I have get issued ssl successfully using ACM and its showing status deployed but when i use https for domain, its not working with error "**This site can’t provide a secure connection**".here is the screenshots

[image]

Questions: Is there need to configure apache too? 
**SSL is issued in Virginia region.**
Please anyone help & guide me for the same.Thanks a lot

Comment: When an SSL certificate is issued, it's ready to use but one needs to install it on the target system. Besides, last time I checked, AWS issued certificates are only usable on ELB (load balancers) and CloudFront (CDN distributions) but not in EC2 servers.

Comment: @marekful: Thanks for your reply. I am using cloudfront but no luck.

Comment: Have you configured your CF distribution to use this certificate?

Comment: Note that this is a certificate for `www.example.com` and `*.example.com`.  It would not work for the bare domain `example.com`.  Is that what you are testing?

Comment: @marekful:Yes,I have configured CF, here is the screenshot of that https://ibb.co/cQOES6

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: so should I request for another one(example.com) ?

Comment: You can request a single cert for both `example.com` and `www.example.com` and that is probably what you will want to do.  You can't modify the existing one and you can only attach one cert to a single CloudFront distribution.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  : I got new  cert and deployed but same error. Do I need to configure apache too ?  Any other suggestion to debug this is error ? below are the screenshots .Thanks
https://ibb.co/ejkjum
https://ibb.co/ihAHEm

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the DNS record actually pointing to CloudFront.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Is your DNS hosted in Route 53, or elsewhere?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Yes, here are the records
https://ibb.co/cWHBUm

Comment: Your A-record for the bare domain is pointing at an IP address.  It should be an Alias pointing to the CloudFront distribution's assigned hostname, `dzzzexample.cloudfront.net`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Thanks for your replies but my issues did not resolve yet.Can you please check my CF settings and apache.conf as below
https://ibb.co/gU3NNG
https://ibb.co/eBwL9w
https://ibb.co/c8FDUw
https://ibb.co/ktqDUw
after adding Alias for CF hostname, getting error  "ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)"

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  Also as you can see (in screenshot), Now there is no record for ec2 instance IP in route 53.I request you to check this.Thanks

Comment: You have www.example.com pointed to CloudFront in DNS, and CloudFront pointed to www.example.com as the origin server.  This creates a loop, where CloudFront tries to connect to itself, resulting in the "Bad request" error.  Create a new A record for your origin, such as "origin.example.com" and set it to the origin server's IP address, then change the CloudFront Origin Domain Name to this new value.  Change Origin Protocol Policy to HTTP-Only, since you do not appear to have an SSL cert on the origin server itself.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Still no luck, getting error "ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I have removed everything except Ec2 instance(I can access content using instance ip). I have domain name example.com that want to use for this Ec2 with ssl certificate(https://www.example.com) .Can you please tell me steps that I need to follow to achieve "https://\www.example.com"  ?
What will be the origin name?
 what dns records will have to create in Route53 ?
I will be very thankful to you.Please help me. Thank you

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Also please let me know if I need to change anything in apache2.conf file ? (port:443 already enabled)